# Storefind the result from smallest error during iteration

Tags: python-2.7, while-loop, iteration

I'm trying to find an iterative solution between my calculation and my measurement.

Suppose I have an instance total irradiance measurement data which I want to separate into two components, namely A and B components.

Let say,
measured irradiance value = 1000 (I name it irrad in the code)
A and B are the diffuse and direct irradiance respectively that can be any value that formed irrad in total.

A (component 1) = 600 and B (component 2) = 400
or
A (component 1) = 300 and B (component 2) = 700

So by some functions, A and B can be derived but for sure there will be a slight difference due to some factors in the calculation.

So in the algorithm,

```
    D=9999
    itercount = 1
    irradx = irrad
    while itercount < 100:
        A,B = f(irradx)
        new_total_irrad = (A*f(x)+B(f(z))) #f(x) and f(z) are another function
        D = (new_total_irrad-irrad)
        if (0<D<=1):
           break
        else:
           irradx = f(D) #another function 
     A,B
```

So in this case, if the iteration does not converge (D>1), I want to get the A and B value when D is the smallest value during 100 loop.

anyone can suggest a pythonic way for this?

Comment: I'm confused by your code. What does the `A, B` at the end do?

Comment: so if I add up A and B it should be resulting irrad value. 
let say,

irrad = 1000.
A and B can be any value that form 1000 if we add up both.
A = 500, B =500
or
A  = 222, B = 778